# Babel error: "Error: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread' from '/vagrant'"

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs

I'm trying to upgrade from Babel 6 -> 7. I used `npx babel-upgrade --write` to assist with updating the `package.json` and then ran a `npm install`.

When trying to run our webpack dev server, it fails to compile with the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread' from '/vagrant'
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (/vagrant/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:58:15)
    at resolveStandardizedName (/vagrant/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:101:31)
    at resolvePlugin (/vagrant/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:54:10)
    at loadPlugin (/vagrant/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:62:20)
    at createDescriptor (/vagrant/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:154:9)
    at items.map (/vagrant/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (/vagrant/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPluginDescriptors (/vagrant/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:105:10)
    at alias (/vagrant/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:63:49)
```

Note `/vagrant` is the project root.

The only references left to `babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread` exist in `node_modules` so my guess is these are triggering it somehow?

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.0.1",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
    "eslint": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^1.6.5",
    "lodash-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.5",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postcss": "^7.0.1",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^3.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.6",
    "postcss-modules-values": "^1.3.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "sinon": "^6.1.4",
    "standard": "^11.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "svg-react-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.7",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "^0.1.11"
  },
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

**Edit:** I've been unable to identify the cause of the issue and have reverted to Babel 6.

Comment: There's an unfortunate difference between `@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` and `babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread`.

Comment: I understand they're different, but it seems `babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread` is no longer supported in Babel 7. What is the alternative? Or am I wrong about this?

Comment: You are not wrong. A good solution will be to convert all dependencies to `Babel 7`. The easy solution will be to install everything that is missing and try until it works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I thought this might have been the case. Unfortunately there are 10+ packages that rely on it so it is no small task. Thanks @Aviad.

Comment: Try to use `yarn why` or the npm equivalent to understand why it's being included

Answer (score 7):

Had this issue and was able to solve it after some digging --

we still had a `transform-object-rest-spread` left in the plugins in our webpack configuration and in our `package.json`, without the babel prefix. Replacing it with `@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` fixed it for us!

Answer (score 3):

If you support legacy project and try to update some dependencies like me.
In your babel config:

```js
{
 plugins: [
   '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread'
 ]
}
```

This is not a "proposal" [anymore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread).
Replace with:

```js
{
 plugins: [
   '@babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread'
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

updated presets from  and used @user14981617's advice.

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/env/ was recommended in terminal.

```
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read https://babeljs.io/env to update!
```

:)

this is what I have currently:

```
{
"presets": [
    ["env", {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "chrome": "60",
          "edge": "60",
          "node": "current"
        }
      }],
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
],
"plugins": [
"@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can be resolve by

```
npm i --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
```